# Where to find Non plug and play drivers sections in device manager?

Tags: windows-xp, device-manager

I'm having a little problem finding the "non-plug and play drivers" section in device manager ( even after I checked "show hidden devices")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to do the "Hidden Devices" tweak , setting  the enviroment variables or the registry for showing that stuff?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315539 (this also works in windows 7)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff184583.aspx

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315539 solved the problem. Thanks a bunch